# Populating two nested grid in one call

Tags: angularjs, kendo-grid

I am using kendo-ui with AngularJS. I have a parent grid and on the expansion of the row I have to show two sub grids, for that I don't want to call server separately. I have developed a service which returns data of both grids, now I want to bind the data to the grid. How to do that? Here is the code:

```
$scope.mainGridOptions = {
        columns: [ 
                   { field: "id", title:"ID",width: "50px" },
                   { field: "name", title:"Name", width:"200px" },                     
                   ],
        dataSource: {               
            transport: {
                read: function (e) {                        
                    var params = {};
                    var dataObj = ServerAPIs.getStudents(params, function(){
                        e.success(dataObj.result);                          
                    },function(){
                        alert('something went wrong');
                    });     
              }
           },
           pageSize: 20,
        },
        sortable: true,
        pageable: {
            refresh: true,
            pageSizes: true,
            buttonCount: 5
        },
        filterable: true,
        reorderable: true,
        resizable: true,
        detailInit: function(e) {
            (function(e){                   
                var params = {
                        "student-id" : e.data.id
                };                  
                var dataObj = ServerAPIs.getStudentDetails(params, function(data){
                    if(data.result.dataset1.length > 0){ 
                        //what to do here? how to access child grid1?
                    }                       
                    if(data.result.dataset2.length > 0){
                        //what to do here? how to access child grid2?
                    }                       
                },function(){
                    alert('something went wrong');
                });
            })(e);
        }
    };
```

Here is the html:

```
<kendo-grid id='maingrid' options="mainGridOptions">
<div k-detail-template >
    <div class='grid_loader'>
        <br/>
            <span class="spinner_forms">&nbsp;</span>
        <br/>
    </div>
    <div class='details' style='display:none'>
        <div class="center-block" style="width: 800px;"  kendo-grid k-options="grid1Options(dataItem)"></div>
        <br />
        <div class="center-block" style="width: 800px;"  kendo-grid k-options="grid2Options(dataItem)"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you get solution for your questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Javascript, I selected child element using find method and initiated the grid.

```
detailInit: function(e) {
        (function(e){                   
            var params = {
                    "student-id" : e.data.id
            };                  
            var dataObj = ServerAPIs.getStudentDetails(params, function(data){
                if(data.result.dataset1.length > 0){ 
                     e.detailRow.find(".child-grid-1").kendoGrid({
                         dataSource: {
                                data: data.result.dataset1,
                            },
                            columns: [//your columns here],
                            //other grid options
                        });
                }                       
                if(data.result.dataset2.length > 0){
                    e.detailRow.find(".child-grid-2").kendoGrid({
                         dataSource: {
                                data: data.result.dataset2,
                            },
                            columns: [//your columns here],
                            //other grid options
                        });
                }                       
            },function(){
                alert('something went wrong');
            });
        })(e);
    }
```

In html page, following modification needs to be made:

```
<kendo-grid id='maingrid' options="mainGridOptions">
<div k-detail-template >
    <div class='grid_loader'>
        <br/>
            <span class="spinner_forms">&nbsp;</span>
        <br/>
    </div>
    <div class='details' style='display:none'>
        <div class="child-grid-1" style="width: 800px;"></div>
        <br />
        <div class="child-grid-2" style="width: 800px;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```